Upgraded upgrade from 13 to 14 error: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: title
After upgrading website from Umbraco 13 to 14 this error happens every time I try to add new item:
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: title
A fatal server error occurred. If this continues, please reach out to your administrator.

So I can't update the website.
The error above is in the Backoffice.
In the console:
POST https://www.xxxx.xxx/umbraco/management/api/v1/document/validate 500 (Internal 
Server Error) POST https://www.xxxx.xxx/umbraco/management/api/v1/document 500 
(Internal Server Error)

And the response is:
{
    "type": "Error",
    "title": "No property editor found by alias 
      Umbraco.MediaPicker",
     "status": 500,
    "detail": "   at 
 
Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.PropertyValidationService.ValidatePropertyValue(IPropertyType propertyType, Object postedValue)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentValidationServiceBase`1.ValidateProperty(ContentEditingModelBase contentEditingModelBase, IPropertyType propertyType, String culture, String segment)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentValidationServiceBase`1.HandlePropertiesValidationAsync(ContentEditingModelBase contentEditingModelBase, TContentType contentType)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentValidationService.ValidatePropertiesAsync(ContentEditingModelBase contentEditingModelBase, IContentType contentType)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentEditingServiceBase`4.ValidatePropertiesAsync(ContentEditingModelBase contentEditingModelBase, TContentType contentType)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentEditingServiceBase`4.ValidatePropertiesAsync(ContentEditingModelBase contentEditingModelBase, Guid contentTypeKey)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentEditingService.ValidateCulturesAndPropertiesAsync(ContentEditingModelBase contentEditingModelBase, Guid contentTypeKey)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentEditingService.ValidateCreateAsync(ContentCreateModel createModel)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Api.Management.Controllers.Document.ValidateCreateDocumentController.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<Validate>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Api.Management.Controllers.Document.CreateDocumentControllerBase.HandleRequest(CreateDocumentRequestModel requestModel, Func`1 authorizedHandler)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Api.Management.Controllers.Document.ValidateCreateDocumentController.Validate(CancellationToken cancellationToken, CreateDocumentRequestModel requestModel)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.BasicAuthenticationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.InterfaceMiddlewareBinder.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<CreateMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Api.Management.Middleware.BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderErrorMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.InterfaceMiddlewareBinder.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<CreateMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfilerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\\projects\\dotnet\\src\\MiniProfiler.AspNetCore\\MiniProfilerMiddleware.cs:line 112\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.InterfaceMiddlewareBinder.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<CreateMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.PreviewAuthenticationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.InterfaceMiddlewareBinder.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<CreateMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestLoggingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.InterfaceMiddlewareBinder.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<CreateMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)",
  "instance": "InvalidOperationException"
  }

How can I resolve it?
Thanks
